# "I want to use my energy TO READ or FOR READING?"

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

Which of these sentences is correct?

> 1) I want to use my energy **to read**.
>
> 2) I want to use my energy **for reading**.

Thank you very much!  Gerunds and infinitives confuse me.

Answer (score 5):

They're both correct.  Which is better to use depends on the context.  For example:

> I want to use my energy to read.

Would be a good statement to use if your intention was to use that energy immediately.

*"Linda!  Let's go out and play!"*

*"No thanks, Jen," said Linda, looking up from her book.  "I want to use my energy to read."*

> I want to use my energy for reading.

Would be a good statement to use if you were simply indicating a preference, or if you were indicating why you were in the process of storing or rationing your energy.

*"John, why aren't you cleaning your room faster?"*

*"I'm sorry, Mom," said John.  "I want to use my energy for reading."

However, colloquially the two statements are so close to identical that they are almost (and often) interchangeable.  Whether one was better than the other would require reading the paragraph or dialog that used one of the sentences.

*Note:* Please note that, in my personal opinion, it's odd to see "energy" used in these sentences.  Reading doesn't consume much energy, and both sentences have the connotation that energy is being saved for a purpose (reading).  "Time," would be a more logical consumable.

> I want to use my time to read.
>
> I want to use my time for reading.

Comment: Thank you!  This is extremely helpful.